# npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near

Tags: angular, angular-cli

when creating a new angular project after running npm install -g @angular/cli I am getting the following error

> npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near
> '...:"^2.1.0","ntypescrip'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\Suraj\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-06-28T06_04_16_049Z-debug.log
> Package install failed, see above.

Answer (score 17):

## Try:-

As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid. If you want to make sure everything is consistent, use '`npm cache verify`' instead. If you're sure you want to delete the entire cache, rerun this command with --force.

**step 1)**

```
$ npm cache clean --force
```

or

```
$ npm cache verify
```

**step 2)**

```
$ npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

or

try uninstalling  and installing `angular/cli`

**step 3)**

```
$ npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

**step 4)**

delete `node_modules` and run `$ npm install`

Comment: `npm cache clean` is deprecated. use `npm cache verify` instead

Answer (score 1):

This solved it for me:

Open Windows Powershell **as admin**

```
npm cache clean --force

npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete npm and npm cache in C:\Users\beni\AppData\Roaming and then re-create your app and then it works fine .