# npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...grity":"sha512-kyAaTj'

Tags: reactjs, firebase, npm, syntax-error, npm-install

While I was trying to install dependencies related to firebase in my react app, I ran npm install --save firebase but it resulted in an error. All other packages required for my app is installed properly except this. What could be the problem with this particular package?

***I have attached the snippet of the error below***

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56801803/npm-err-unexpected-end-of-json-input-while-parsing-near

Comment: Following the steps in the link will cost me much as it is a very big project and I cannot force clean the cache. 
Can you please suggest some other way and give the reason as to why did this happen?